# c# blocking code in async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, win-universal-app

I’m using MvvmCross and the [AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) library within a Windows 10 (UWP) App.

In a ViewModel, I have an INotifyTaskCompletion property (1) which is wired-up to an Async method in the ViewModel (2)

In (2), I call an Async library method which:

- Checks a local cache
- Downloads data asynchronously
- Adds the data to the cache

The caching code cannot be made asynchronous and so the library method contains both blocking and asynchronous code.

Q. What’s the best way to prevent blocking the UI thread?

I understand from [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) to not to block in asynchronous code and not use Task.Run in library methods. So do I have to….

Move the caching calls into (2) e.g.

- Use Task.Run (to check the cache)
- Call the library method asynchronously
- Use Task.Run again (to cache the data)?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you some code you could share?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "better". If you can't change the cache code and want to use async/await, then using `Task.Run()` for the caching code is "correct".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have completely synchronous code which you can't change to make it return an awaitable, and want to make it asynchronous, then yes, your only choice if you want to use `async/await` is to use `Task.Run()`.

Something like:

```
public async Task<T> MyMethod()
{
   T result = await Task.Run(() => CheckCacheOnSyncMethodICantChange());
   if(result != null)
   {
     result = await MyLibraryMethodThatReturnsATask();
     await Task.Run(() => AddToCacheOnSyncMethodICantChange(result));
   }
   return result;
}
```

Should be ok.

Comment: Despite my answer, and for your specific case, a cache should be fast (that's the reason you use it)... Are you sure you need to make the cache methods asynchronous?

Comment: I'm using SQLite.net to cache the data in a file-based database. Because this work is non-CPU bound, I want to do it without blocking the UI thread. Have I missed something?

Comment: @Howard no, it's fine... as long as your library method takes significant more time than checking and adding to the cache. I'm not experienced with SQLite, but I recall having seen an `SQLiteAsyncConnection` somewhere if you are using `SQLite.Net` which had `GetAsync` and `InsertAsync`

Comment: I believe the SQLite.net async library methods are simply doing a Task.Run around the sync library methods, which is described as an anti-pattern (by some).

Comment: @Howard yes, actually, `Task.Factory.StartNew`, it seems: https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net.Async/SQLiteAsyncConnection.cs . Well, there's just no good solution. If your calling code (i.e., `MyMethod` in my answer) is a "caling method", and not a "library method" (and it should be, since you don't want your libraries to depend on an sqlite file database :-) ), then using `Task.Run` is just ok